# How to remove QueryString in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an URL `http://sitename.com/#/products/manage-options/31?form_id=32&type=create-template`

Here above my URL  I want to remove `type` but below my code not working properly. Please Check

My Current page URL - `http://sitename.com/#/products/manage-options/31?type=create-template`

```
<a href="" ng-click="clickMe();">Click Here</a>

$scope.clickMe = function(){
  $location.search('type', null);
  $state.go('products.manage_options', ({form_id: $stateParams.form_id}));
};
```

After page redirecting I saw `type` QueryString not removed.

My output is -  `http://sitename.com/#/products/manage-options/31?form_id=32&type=create-template` I want `http://sitename.com/#/products/manage-options/31?form_id=32`

please help me.

EDIT:

Router

```
.state('products.manage_options', {
        url: '/manage-options/:product_id?form_id=&type',
        templateUrl: "views/product/manage_options.html",
        controller: "manageAttributeCtrl",
        data: {pageTitle: 'Manage Options'},
})
```

Comment: what is the URL target of your state 'products.manage_options' ?

Comment: @JuniorDev I have updated my code.

Comment: Might be worth to specify `({form_id: $stateParams.form_id}, {type: ''})` @Chinu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove

```
$location.search('type', null);
```

Change following line :

```
$state.go('products.manage_options', ({form_id: $stateParams.form_id, type:null}));
```

Answer (score 1):

see documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#search

```
     $state.go('products.manage_options', ({form_id: $stateParams.form_id, type:null}));
```